# can't access public fields in class | c++

Tags: c++, class, field, public

I've got this class here
(this is a .h file)

```
    #ifndef STORE_H_
    #define STORE_H_

    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    #include "list.h"
    #include "Album.h"
    #include "Customer.h"


class Store {

    public:
static const int currentYear = 2013;
Store();
void addAlbum(int barcode, int price, int year, int numPurchased, string title,                             string artist);
void removeAlbum(int barcode);
void addCustomer(int id, string name);
void createNewOrder(int id, int ordNum);
void addToOrder(int ordNum, int barcode);
void removeFromOrder(int ordNum, int barcode);
void payOrder(int ordNum);
string getRecommendations(int numOfRecommendations) const;
string getInventoryReport() const;
string getCustomersReport() const;
string getCustomerReport(int id) const;
string getRevenueReport() const;
~Store();

bool albumsCompare(Album album1, Album album2);
bool customerCompare(Customer customer1, Customer customer2);
std::set<Album> albums;
std::set<Customer> customers;

};

#endif /* STORE_H_ */
```

and i'm trying to access the set "albums"

```
std::set<Album> albums;
```

from here (the .cpp file)

```
void addAlbum(int barcode, int price, int year, int numPurchased, string title, string artist) {


    if(barcode <= 0){
        throw INVALID_BARCODE();
    }

    if(price <= 0){
        throw INVALID_PRICE{};
    }

    if(year > Store::currentYear){
        throw INVALID_YEAR();
    }

    if(numPurchased < 0){
        throw INVALID_NUM_PURCHASED();
    }

    if(Album::findBarcode(Store::albums, barcode) != Store::albums.end()){
        throw BARCODE_ALREADY_EXISTS();
    }
}
```

but i'm getting the error: cannot call member function 'std::set::iterator Album::findBarcode(const std::set&, const int&)'

any help in solving this would be much appreciated!

here is the findBarcode function

```
#include "Album.h"




std::set<Album>::iterator Album::findBarcode (std::set<Album>& set,int& barcode){
 Album data = Album();
for (std::set<Album>::iterator i = set.begin(); i != set.end(); i++){
     Album data = *i;
     if(data.barcode == barcode){
            return i;
     }
}
return set.end();

}
```

Comment: If you made your `barcode`, `price`, `year`, and `numPurchased` as **unsigned** int, you would not need all the checking for negativity.

Answer (score 5):

You are defining a non-member function `addAlbum`, unrelated to your member function of the same name. You need to put your member function definition in the `Store` scope:

```
void Store::addAlbum(int barcode, int price, int year, int numPurchased, string title, string artist)
{//  ^^^^^
  ....
}
```

Comment: Not the question asked, but, @user2266935 should also make his data members private.

Comment: Thanks man, but now i'm getting this error: cannot call member function 'std::set<Album>::iterator Album::findBarcode(const std::set<Album>&, const int&)' without object

any ideas ?

Comment: @user2266935 You should definitely be using `albums` instead of `Store::albums` there. But there might be other problems. Can't say without knowing more about `Album::findBarCode`.

Answer (score 0):

by default in c++ when we create a class  all fields are privates.
You can also create you class with struct key word are all your fields and methods will be public

Comment: That's nice, but the error here is statically accessing a non-static member, not permissions.

Comment: First: The OP has put the public keyword at the top of his class definition.  Second: Let's not encourage people to use structs for complex objects.